# How to delete everything outside of selection on layer

Tags: gimp

I'm learning GIMP little by little.

I need to deleted everything outside my selection (make everything outside transparent).

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You should probably try some basic beginner tutorials on youtube. But anyway, you need to do Select > Invert, then you can delete what's outside of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Select>Invert` (Ctrl-I)
- `Edit>Clear` ([delete])